# prevent refresh button to store old data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a register page and I am having problem when storing the data.
When I successfully register, it stores to database.
But when I reload it again, it automatically stores the same old data I typed to database.
How to solve this problem?

My simple php code looks like this

```
if (empty($fname)) {
    echo '';
} else {
    $success = ("
        INSERT INTO customer
            (FName, LName, Email, Password, MobileNum, PostalCode)
        VALUES
            ('$fname','$lname', '$email', '$password', '$mobilenumber','$postalcode')
    ");
    mysql_query($success);
    echo 'success';
}
?>
```

Comment: @HaimEvgi There's no accepted answer there. The tags aren't the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming that you're using an HTTP POST request when you "store" the data, the easiest way to ensure that re-loading the page doesn't do a re-POST of the same data is to do a redirect at the end of your script.

Instead of doing `echo 'success'` do `Header("Location: ?")`

That way, the browser does a GET immediately after the POST. If the user refreshes the resulting page, they simply re-request the GET. (or do nothing at all if caching is in play).

Answer (score 0):

You can check in database before inserting...

```
if(empty($fname)){
    echo '';
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE FName='$fname'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numRows==0) {
        $success=("INSERT INTO customer (FName, LName, Email, Password, MobileNum, PostalCode) VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$email', '$password', '$mobilenumber','$postalcode')");
        mysql_query($success);
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo "Already exists";  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After success you may [unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) $_POST and if there is any output with echo or html you may use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect to another page

```
if (empty($fname)) {
    //   echo '';
} else {
    $success = ("INSERT INTO customer (FName, LName, Email, Password, MobileNum, PostalCode) VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$email', '$password', '$mobilenumber','$postalcode')");
    mysql_query($success);
    unset($_POST);
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/successPage.php')
    /** if you don't able to use header, you may echo a javascrript redirect
      echo '<script>window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/successPage.php"';</script>";
     */
    // echo 'success';
}
```